# SignalR function handler React doesnt know state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-signalr

I'm trying to understand basics of SignalR. I created a project in React and backend in asp.net core 6 with web api. On server Side I implemented Hub and from React connected to it. On client side code looks like that:

```
const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
const [connection, setConnection] = useState<HubConnection>();

const MyLog = (message: string) => {
console.log(message)
console.log(counter)
}

useEffect(() => {
connect();
  }, []);

const connect = async (): Promise<void> => {
    const connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
      .withUrl(import.meta.env.VITE_SIGNALR)
      .configureLogging(LogLevel.Information)
      .build();

    connection.on("ReceiveMyMessage", (message) => {
      MyLog(message);
    });

    await connection.start();
    setConnection(connection);
};
```

So basically everything works and when some kind of operation on the backednd is done then MyLog(message) function is invoked on all clients and message is passed so ok. But, as you can see in the code, I also have in this component counter state ionitially set to 0. I also have a button to increment the counter state by 1 aftrer each click.

And it works on client side. So i have new refreshed website, counter is set to 0 and signalR connection is established. Then I hit button 5 times and I can see in the client logs that counter state is 5. But then when I send message from backend MyLog function sees value of counter as 0. In other words when I receive SignalR message in my react component it doesnt know the state of component which is constantly updated by user in browser.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is a common JavaScript closure problem, you can use `useRef` to fix it.

**Here is the sample.**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { HubConnection, HubConnectionBuilder, LogLevel } from '@microsoft/signalr';

const TheTestComponent = () => {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
  const [connection, setConnection] = useState<HubConnection>();
  const counterRef = useRef(counter); // Add useRef here

  // update the value of counter  in counterRef
  useEffect(() => {
    counterRef.current = counter;
    connect();
  }, [counter]);

  const MyLog = (message: string) => {
    console.log(message);
    console.log(counterRef.current); // save the latest value of counter in useRef 
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const connect = async (): Promise<void> => {
      const newConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
        .withUrl(import.meta.env.VITE_SIGNALR)
        .configureLogging(LogLevel.Information)
        .build();

      newConnection.on("ReceiveMyMessage", (message) => {
        MyLog(message);
      });

      await newConnection.start();
      setConnection(newConnection);
    };

    connect();
  }, []);

  // ... 

  return (
    // ... 
  );
};

export default TheTestComponent;
```